# How do I populate two form fields - one with coordinates, one with address - using the HERE API?

Tags: javascript, geocoding, here-api

What I'm trying to implement is a button that when clicked returns the address that the user is closest to and populates a form field with this data. So far I have been able to use the HTML Geolocation API and return a user's current coordinates to a form field. So what I'd like to add on top of this is for those coordinates to be reverse geocoded into the street address and returned to a different form field. I'm trying to use the HERE API to achieve the reverse geocoding part of this problem, but - as I said - I suck at JS and don't really know how the code should look.

The code I have for returning the user's coordinates is here and works fine:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var currentLocation = document.getElementById('coordinatesStore');
    document.querySelector('.add-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({
                coords: {
                    latitude,
                    longitude
                }
            }) => {
                currentLocation.value = latitude + ", " + longitude;
            });
        } else {
            currentLocation.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    });
}
```

The code for reverse geocoding coordinates from an example on the API [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/geocoding.html) is below but I can't work out how to integrate the two:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    app_id: 'blahblahblah',
    app_code: 'rararararararr'
});

function reverseGeocode(platform) {
  var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService(),
    parameters = {
      prox: latitude + ", " + longitude,
      mode: 'retrieveAddresses',
      maxresults: '1'};

  geocoder.reverseGeocode(parameters,
    function (result) {
      alert(result);
    }, function (error) {
      alert(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example. Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
async function getLongLat() {
  //adding promise just for safe side to get it resolve first
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let longitude = 'a',
        latitude = 'b'
    resolve( {
      longitude,
      latitude
    });   
  });
}

async function reverseGeocode(platform) {
  //var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService(),
  try {
    const {latitude, longitude} = await getLongLat();
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
  }catch(err){
    //here error is getLongLat reject for any XYZ reason
  }
  
}

reverseGeocode()
```

Comment: I don't see how this coverts the coordinates into an address.